# Okta - Need to Redirect/Relay SSO to Azure/Office Portal to a Web Application

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, okta, ws-federation

I have a web application that, due to certain technical limitations can only be setup for SSO with Azure AD. We use Okta for SSO, and have our Azure AD setup to authenticate against our Okta tenant via WS-Federation. The web application is configured for SSO from our Azure/Office portal.

I was hoping to find out if there's a way to launch our web application from our Okta portal by sending the user to Azure first to complete the SSO authentication process (without entering their creds), and then onward to our web application, similar to doing a RelayState config in SAML?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - which is to use an Office 365 Smart Link, which you can use the tool at http://m-rk.github.io/o365-smart-link/ to generate.